# Linux AttackLab touch2 - the address of the code change after running the code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm solving "Attacklab touch2".
Before running the code, I checked the address of "touch2" by 'info addr touch2'.

**"touch2" is a function at address 0x19f9.**

addr of **"main" is 0x1341.** Then, make the breakpoint at "getbuf" by 'b getbuf' and run the code.
Now, it said.

**"touch2" is a function at address 0x5555555559f9.**

**"main" is a function at address 0x555555555341.**

---

If I made file named answer2.s like

```
pushq $0x19f9
movq $0x65d471b5, %rdi
retq
```

it said this is not correct answer.

Then if I tried

```
pushq $0x5555555559f9
movq $0x65d471b5, %rdi
retq
```

`gcc -c answer2.s`
error code :
answer2.s: Assembler messages:
answer2.s:1: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You asked for the address before the program was run and thus relocated. This is normal behavior. An address so low as 0x19f9 should raise a few flags.

Comment: `pushq` can only take a 32-bit immediate, to be sign-extended to 64.  Unfortunately GAS error messages often don't explain the real reason why an instruction couldn't be encoded; NASM tends to be better, and would warn "signed dword immediate exceeds bounds".  Best bet is to use a register, like `mov $0x5555555559f9, %r11` / `jmp *%r11`.  (If you're using a register, you don't need push reg/ret anymore.)